# ruby code to search and get a string from a html content

Tags: ruby

Am new to ruby.
am trying to get the webpage contents and search and return a string from that response
following code retunrs the webpage as html

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'


AppArgs = Array.new

def get()
content = Net::HTTP.get('integration.twosmiles.com', '/status')
puts content
end

get()
```

html content

```
<!-- PAGE CONTENT -->
<div class="container-fluid page-content">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <h1>Status</h1>
<p>The rails app is up.  Nothing to see here, move on.</p>
<br>
<p>uptime:</p>
 22:09:18 up 66 days, 22:37,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
<br>

<br><br>
<p>other</p>
# On branch deploy
<br>
commit bc1407b29697bab36bc2f5e35aa197228181e225
<br>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->
```

Above is the part of the web page content . From this content i want to get the `commit bc1407b29697bab36bc2f5e35aa197228181e225`
and ony want to return the key value `bc1407b29697bab36bc2f5e35aa197228181e225`.how it is possbile using ruby code

Comment: Try with nokigiri parsing gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
key = get()[/commit\s+([a-f0-9]{10,})/i, 1]
puts key
```

Regex explanation [**here**](http://regex101.com/r/zN5nK0).

Comment: can u please describe the meaning of this regular experssion?